# Change xlam udf destination cell format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have below UDF to calculate CAGR created in XLAM file which is shared with other users.

```
Public Function CAGR(StartValue, EndValue, Periods) As Double
CAGR = (EndValue / StartValue) ^ (1 / Periods) - 1
End Function
```

We have added a custom UI button shortcut to this formula.
This code is working fine and generated result is in decimal format.

Please help to find how can we add below 2 functionalities in this UDF.

1. We need destination cell format to automatically change to this
   format 12.3%, currently by default result is shown as 0.12.
2. Also we need Periods to be count of filled cells if multiple cells are
   selected.

I know we formula can't change cell format. Is there any way to call formula popup from vba to achieve this, so that we can first change the format from code and then show the formula popup?

Comment: see my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588153/value-error-setting-interior-colorindex-property-in-excel-2013/50588539#50588539) for a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know you cannot change any cells format with a UDF called by a formula. Therefore the only way I can imagine to do that automatically is to hook up the `Worksheet_Change` event as a workaround.

So the following will change to numberformat to % when a cell is changed to a formula starting with `=CAGR`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tCell As Range
    For Each tCell In Target.Cells
        If Left$(tCell.Formula, 5) = "=CAGR" Then 'if formula begins with =CAGR
            tCell.NumberFormat = "#.##%" 'change number format
        End If
    Next tCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Any suggestion for second question please?

Comment: @aditya I don't understand what you mean by your second question exactly. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: For 3rd variable if user selects a range from sheet, we need to set count of all cells in variable.

Comment: @aditya can you please edit your original question and add an example for that how that formula would look like in the cell?